# Why is not optional the Tcl optional argument here?

Tags: tcl

In the code below I want to take a variable number of arguments, even zero argument.
But the interpreter says wrong argument number error.

```
% interp alias {} func {} proc
% func var {varname = args} {
  if {$args eq ""} {
    set varname
  } else {
    upvar $varname v
    set v $args
  }
}
% var part1 = Sal
Sal
% puts $part1
Sal
% var part1
wrong # args: should be "var varname = ?arg ...?"
```

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arguments that you provide all get passed through to the procedure. The procedure has been declared *by* you to take three arguments, formally called `varname`, `=` and `args` (where the last one is special and receives a list of all remaining arguments). This means it has two mandatory arguments, and a completely unbounded number of optional arguments.

If you want `=` to be an optional argument, you have to give it a default value in the declaration, perhaps like this:

```
# I've put the value in quotes for highlighting purposes only
proc var {varname {= "="} args} {
```

(You can call it `func` if you want, but I'll use the standard name.)

If formal parameters have default values, they are considered to be optional when the procedure is called. However, they consume arguments *before* the final `args` does.

---

I recommend using `[llength $args] == 0` to check for list emptiness, not `$args eq ""`; the latter forces a conversion-to-string and can be expensive.

Overall, this is much closer to idiomatic (and basically a long winded way of writing something *almost* like the standard `set` command.)

```
proc var {varname {= "="} args} {
    upvar 1 $varname v
    if {[llength $args]} {
        set v $args
    }
    return $v
}
```

Comment: It is a perfect explanation, now I understand the faulty part. And the llength check is very useful. Thank you very much!